# How to customize calendar notification through java code

Tags: java, google-calendar-api

Currently by default notification in calendar is of 10 minutes. I need to customize it for 0 minutes. I am able to customize title, description, reminder by passing query parameters in Calendar URL through java code. Below is the code snippet as how I am doing for text, details and dates.

```
URIBuilder uri = new URIBuilder("http://www.google.com/calendar/event");
uri.addParameter("action", "TEMPLATE");
uri.addParameter("dates", eventStartDate + "/" + eventEndDate);
uri.addParameter("text", eventTitle);
uri.addParameter("details", eventDescription);
uri.addParameter("crm", visibility);            
return uri.build().toString();
```

Comment: Have you tried sendUpdates?

Answer (score 0):

### Answer

*Use the field [reminders](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/concepts/reminders#overriding_default_reminders) of the [event resource](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events#resource).*

### How it works

Take a look to the [Java Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/quickstart/java), it is easy to use the official [API client libraries](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/quickstart/quickstarts-overview) which hide some of the details of the authentication and authorization flow. Also take a read to the documentation about how to [Create Events](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/guides/create-events#java):

```java
Event event = new Event()
    .setSummary("Google I/O 2015")
    .setLocation("800 Howard St., San Francisco, CA 94103")
    .setDescription("A chance to hear more about Google's developer products.");

// more things...

EventReminder[] reminderOverrides = new EventReminder[] {
    new EventReminder().setMethod("email").setMinutes(0),
    new EventReminder().setMethod("popup").setMinutes(0),
};

Event.Reminders reminders = new Event.Reminders()
    .setUseDefault(false)
    .setOverrides(Arrays.asList(reminderOverrides));
event.setReminders(reminders);

String calendarId = "primary";
event = service.events().insert(calendarId, event).execute();
System.out.printf("Event created: %s\n", event.getHtmlLink());
```

### References

- [Overriding default reminders](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/concepts/reminders#overriding_default_reminders)
- [Event resource](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events#resource)
- [Calendar API: Create Events](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/guides/create-events#java)
- [Calendar API: Java Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/quickstart/java)

Comment: Currently I am using this endpoint "http://www.google.com/calendar/event". For the above suggested solution, do I have to set up a new Calendar API as I am not getting any suggestion for Event in my code. Please suggest.